# PHP Mysql database connection being refused

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a simple table of one of the tables in my mySQL database, but am getting the below message when I load the page.

```
connection failed:Connection refused
Username    Password    PhysicianID
```

I have tested the credentials I use in my code over and over and am 100% sure that they are correct.  I am unsure as to what could be causing this issue.  Below is my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
<TITLE>Table That will NOT load</TITLE>
 </head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>PhysicianId</th>
    </tr>

<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('host', 'root', 'password', 'MySQLDatabase');
    if(!$conn) {
        die("connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "Select * from Users";
    $result = $conn-> query($sql);

    if($result -> num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td><td>". $row["username"] ."</td><td>". $row["username"] ."</td><td>". $row[
                "password"] ."</td><tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        else {
            echo "0 result";
        }

        $conn-> close();
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your host name ?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the same symptoms? here is a [google search for you](https://www.google.com.tr/search?biw=1920&bih=974&ei=7-9kWpS8H8WasAGI8Ly4BA&q=mysqli+connection+refused+site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=mysqli+connection+refused+site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...76929.76929.0.77100.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Vx6kjLnThos)

Comment: `'host'` is usually `'localhost'` or `'127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that the mysql server is bound to the expected IP which is assigned to the `host` value you are using in `mysql_connect`.

- Find out IP: `nslookup <host>`
- On the Host, check bind address of `mysql`process: `ps -eaf | grep mysql`. (0.0.0.0/0 means bind on all IPs of the Host and is fine)

If you get different IPs for both commands, that is the culprit. Esp. if the second one only returns 127.0.0.1. You need to adjust your mysql configuration to bind on the external IP address of the Host then.

Comment: I was not even thinking, I was using the address of my server, not even realizing that is where the mysql was hosted, so just needed to switch the host of my server url to 'localhost'

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine but in this line:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('host', 'root', 'password', 'MySQLDatabase');
```

Check if your host name and password is correct. If you use localhost and your password is not defined it should be:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'MySQLDatabase');
```

Also, check your HTML in php. You have two `<td>` tags on beggining and using this order of `$row` you will get password under PhysicianId in table.

Try this:

```
if($result -> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>". $row["username"] ."</td><td>". $row["password"] ."</td><td>". $row[
            "id"] ."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else {
        echo "0 result";
    }
```